# Dirac's pseudo-energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Having trouble with Dirac's eq. (31.3) ("General Theory of Relativity"). Probably a simple math question, but I need to provide a little background on the symbols.

Dirac defines the pseudo-energy tensor $t_\mu^{\enspace\nu}$ by
$$t_\mu^{\enspace\nu}\sqrt{-g}=\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}}g_{\alpha\beta,\mu}-g^\nu_\mu\,\mathscr{L}.\qquad(*)$$

Here $g=\text{det}(g_{\mu\nu})$, and $\mathscr{L}$ is the action density (in four dimensions) or the Lagrangian density (in three dimensions); that is, Einstein's field equations are equivalent to $\delta I=0$ where $I=\int{\mathscr{L}d^4x} = \int{dx_0\int{\mathscr{L}dx^1dx^2dx^3}}$.

Earlier (Ch. 26) Dirac defined $\mathscr{L}\equiv L\sqrt{-g}$, where the scalar $L$ is a complicated combination of the metric tensor and Christoffel symbols (not important for this question). If you're interested, $L = g^{\mu\nu}(\Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\rho_{\sigma\rho}-\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\sigma}\Gamma^\sigma_{\nu\rho})$.

Dirac says in Eq. (31.3) that $(*)$ implies:
$$t_\mu^{\enspace\nu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}}g_{\alpha\beta,\mu}-g^\nu_\mu\,L.$$

It's obvious what he's done. Plugging $\mathscr{L}=L\sqrt{-g}$ into $(*)$:

$$t_\mu^{\enspace\nu}\sqrt{-g} = \frac{\partial (L\sqrt{-g})}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}}g_{\alpha\beta,\mu}-g^\nu_\mu\,L\sqrt{-g}.\qquad(**)$$

Dirac is just cancelling the $\sqrt{-g}$. But surely the product rule gives:

$$\frac{\partial (L\sqrt{-g})}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} \sqrt{-g} + \frac{\partial \sqrt{-g}}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} L.$$

Does the last term vanish? In fact, we know from an earlier chapter (Eq. (20.6)) that $(\sqrt{-g})_{,\rho} = \Gamma^\tau_{\rho\tau}\sqrt{-g}$. So

$$\frac{\partial \sqrt{-g}}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} = \frac{\partial \sqrt{-g}}{\partial x^\rho} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} = \frac{(\sqrt{-g})_{,\rho}}{g_{\alpha\beta,\nu\rho}} = \frac{\Gamma^\tau_{\rho\tau}\sqrt{-g}}{g_{\alpha\beta,\nu\rho}}.$$

Whatever this quantity is, it doesn't look like zero. Or to be more exact, the term
$$\frac{\Gamma^\tau_{\rho\tau}\sqrt{-g}}{g_{\alpha\beta,\nu\rho}}g_{\alpha\beta,\mu}$$
which should show up in $(**)$ does not look like zero. Or is it?

Comment: In $\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{L}(g_{\alpha \beta},g_{\alpha \beta ,\nu})$ the $g_{\alpha \beta}$ and $g_{\alpha \beta ,\nu}$ are treated as independent variables (like treating $x$ and $v = \dot{x}$ as independent), so when he takes a partial derivative w.r.t.  $g_{\alpha \beta ,\nu}$ it slides right past the $\sqrt{-g}$ term i.e. it's derivative w.r.t.  $g_{\alpha \beta ,\nu}$ does vanish, so he can immediately just cancel the $\sqrt{-g}$ terms as he does.

Comment: I know what you mean (viz. $x$, $\dot{x}$, etc.) but: $L$ is a jumble of the metric and various derivatves of the metric (as shown in the formula for $L$ above), and similarly $\sqrt{-g}$ is a jumble of components of the metric. So why should a derivative with respect to anything just "slide" past $\sqrt{-g}$?

Comment: Are you saying that it is fundamentally wrong to reason this way:
$$\frac{\partial \sqrt{-g}}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} = \frac{\partial \sqrt{-g}}{\partial x^\rho} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}} = \frac{(\sqrt{-g})_{,\rho}}{g_{\alpha\beta,\nu\rho}} = \frac{\Gamma^\tau_{\rho\tau}\sqrt{-g}}{g_{\alpha\beta,\nu\rho}}$$

Comment: From $\delta g = g g^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}$ you can see there is no $\delta g_{\mu \nu,\rho}$ term in there, if you trivially write it as $\delta g = g g^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu} + 0 \cdot \delta g_{\mu \nu,\rho}$ you see it's $g_{\mu \nu,\rho}$ derivative is zero without question. Even if it somehow made sense to treat $x^{\rho}$ as a function of a derivative of the metric (at the point $x$), the rest of these equalities don't look right, and the result has to be zero anyway because of what I just said. He would have added more detail if he was doing something this complicated.